# Incompatible value for Quickbase Date Field

Tags: json, quickbase

I have a feature where I update the values on Quickbase for our system.
I am able to update most fields, checkboxes, text inputs and numerical data..

using  this kind of query

```json
{
    "to":"appid",
    "data": [
        {
            "3": { "value": 1 },
            "308": { "value": "2021-5-17" },
            "104": { "value": true }
        }
    ]
}
```

but when I try updating a value on a date field.. I get a '207 Multi-Status' response from it.
any idea how to set date values?

I tried different string formats. Quickbase formulas/functions like 'today()'
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The format of your date is not quite correct. This API is very strict about the format YYYY-MM-DD so you should use `"308": { "value": "2021-05-17" }`.  You can use some other keywords such as `today` for the value as described in the [field type documentation](https://developer.quickbase.com/fieldInfo). Also, if you are actually using the application Id for `appId` that will also cause problems since a table ID is expected there instead.

There could be other errors and the 207 Multi-Status code alone doesn't give much of a hint about what went wrong.  If you can, look at the response body where you should see an error description returned from Quickbase that would look something like this:

```
{
  "data": [],
  "metadata": {
    "createdRecordIds": [],
    "lineErrors": {
      "1": [
        "Incompatible value for field with ID \"308\"."
    ]
   },
   "totalNumberOfRecordsProcessed": 1,
   "unchangedRecordIds": [],
   "updatedRecordIds": []
  }
}
```